# Script is only working correctly on the first run

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, reddit

The script has to fetch posts from api and save them into the database.

After running the script that runs successfully, it won't be able to fetch new posts even if there are some new for another 5-24+ hours.
It will return the same old response every time in fraction of second like it was running from cache or something. (if I remove the old posts, it still adds them to the db)

What is interesting is that if I deploy same script, it runs ok for the first time and then again, I have to wait for another 5-24+ hours.

If it is running successfully, it takes like 3-10 second, otherwise it takes less than a second.

I'm really confused with it, is there something like caching responses ? Or may this be a problem on reddit api side ? Would adding any of this options help ?

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 100,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 100
```

I'm currently using requests library for request

```
r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-agent': 'My App 12345'})
response = r.json()
```

Here is the GAE part of my script

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    # --------------- Database Connection ---------------
    global db
    global cursor

    if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/'):
        db = MySQLdb.connect(xxx)
    else:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(xxx)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    # ---------------------------------------------------
    fetchFromReddit("") # Start fetching script

    self.response.write("Finished !")

    db.close()
    cursor.close()

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/url', MainHandler)
    ], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Appengine URL Fetch service does [appear](http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleAppEngine/2010-02/msg00761.html) to cache responses. As mentioned in this [google appengine group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/TnSreTqcbQM), To by-pass/disable the cache, you need to add this to you request headers:

```
headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache,max-age=0', 'Pragma': 'no-cache'}
```

Where `"max-age"` is the oldest you want data returned from the cache to 
be.